# ¿Se puede setear el valor de un atributo llamando a otra función que no sea set?

Tags: php, poo, funciones, set

Tengo definida esta clase abstracta usuario, con un metodo publico para crear la cuenta de usuario, que segun sea de un tipo u otro de clase que hereda me cree una `$cuentaUsuario` específica, lo que pasa es que no se como puedo retornar el valor de esa función con `setCuentaUsuario` cuando quiero cambiar los datos manualmente desde el index por ejemplo.

```
<?php
abstract class Usuario {
//Atributos

protected $nombre;
protected $apellido1;
protected $apellido2;
private $cuentaUsuario;


//Constructores
function __construct(string $nombre,string $apellido1,string $apellido2){
 $this->nombre=$nombre;
 $this->apellido1=$apellido1;
 $this->apellido2=$apellido2;
} 

//Destructores
//Getters y Setters
public function getNombre(){
 return $this->nombre;
}
public function setNombre($pNombre)   {
 $this->nombre=$pNombre;
}
public function getApellido1(){
 return $this->apellido1;
}
public function setApellido1($pApellido1){
 $this->apellido1=$pApellido1;
}
public function getApellido2(){
 return $this->apellido2;
}
public function setApellido2($pApellido2){
 $this->apellido2=$pApellido2;
}

public function getCuentaUsuario(){
 return $this->cuentaUsuario;
}
public function setCuentaUsuario(){
 $this->cuentaUsuario=$cuentaUsuario;
}


//Metodos
public abstract function __toString();

public abstract function consultar($pDato);

public abstract function buscarUsuario($pDni);

function crearCuenta($pObj){#preguntar si es o no correcto
    if ($pObj instanceof Secretario){
        $cuentaUsuario='S'.date('y').substr($this->getNombre(),4);//reultado esperado 'S19nomb'
        return $this->setCuentaUsuario($cuentaUsuario);
    }elseif ($pObj instanceof Profesor) {
        $cuentaUsuario='P'.date('y').substr($this->getNombre(),4);
        return $this->setCuentaUsuario($cuentaUsuario);
    }elseif ($pObj instanceof Alumno) {
        $cuentaUsuario='A'.date('y').substr($this->getNombre(),4);
        return $this->setCuentaUsuario($cuentaUsuario);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: En la clase `Usuario` el parámetro `$cuentaUsuario` no tiene punto de entrada por ninguna parte. De todos modos este tipo de situaciones deberían resolverse mediante herencia de clases. En lugar de tener un método `crearCuenta()`, sería mejor declarar que `Secretario, Profesor y Alumno` extienden de `Usuario` y en el constructor de cada una de esas clases llamar al constructor de la clase padre con `parent`. No le veo sentido por tanto a un método `crearCuenta()` en la clase `Usuario`, eso es en cierto sentido una negación de la herencia.

Comment: gracias, he borrado la funcion y asignado en cada clase el atributo cuenta de usuario, y ya me funciona, la verdad es que tiene mas sentido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta me parece ambigua, en el título preguntas por **setear** y en el cuerpo preguntas por **obtener**.

De todas formas el método que comentas no realiza ninguna de las dos acciones, pues no espera ningún parámetro ni devuelve ningún valor, donde pones:

```
public function setCuentaUsuario(){
 $this->cuentaUsuario=$cuentaUsuario;
}
```

Deberias cambiarlo por:

```
public function setCuentaUsuario($cuentaUsuario){
 $this->cuentaUsuario=$cuentaUsuario;
 return $this->cuentaUsuario;
}
```

Y respondiendo al título tomado literalmente, la respuesta sería **SI**, cualquier método de la clase puede modificar el valor de una variable si está [visible](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php) en dicho ámbito, por ejemplo:

```
public function importar_usuario($datosUsuario){
 $this->cuentaUsuario=$datosUsuario->cuenta;
 // .... 
 return true;
}
```

Comment: gracias por la aclaración y por fijarte en que no pasaba ningun parametro en el set, de tanto modificar y borrar y volver a escribir, se olvidan modificaciones que se hacen y luego no te fijas y no es el fallo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que estás creando código spaghetti en tu método `crearCuenta()`, renunciando a ciertos beneficios de la herencia de clases.

En ese método parece que quieres generar una especie de código para cada tipo de `Usuario`, según sea un `Secretario`, un `Alumno` o un `Profesor`.

La herencia de clases trabaja de otro modo, el principio es muy simple, digamos que tienes una clase padre, que más propiamente sería `Persona`, y varias clases que *heredan* de dicha clase. ¿Qué heredan? Todo lo que tendrían en común todas las personas. Entonces, en cada clase hija recibes todos los parámetros relativos a esa clase y en su constructor organizas la distribución de propiedades.

Veamos un ejemplo con código para que nos entendamos.

Aquí tenemos una clase `Persona` y una clase `Secretario`. La clase `Secretario` hereda de `Persona`, recibe en el constructor todas las propiedades de un `Secretario`, por supuesto que un `Secretario` tiene nombre, apellido... porque es una `Persona`, entonces, le pasas a `Persona` usando `parent` las propiedades que le corresponden, y en `Secretario` te quedas con las propiedades que son sólo suyas, en este caso sería solamente una: `$propioDeSecretario`.

Fíjate que incluso la especie de código que quieres generar no se recibe en parámetro, porque es algo auto-generado. Pero eso ocurre en el constructor de `Secretario`.

Haciendo las cosas así no creas un código spaghetti. En la POO las cosas tienen que funcionar como en la vida real, esa es una de sus ventajas.

Veamos ahora el ejemplo y hagamos pruebas. Espero que entiendas el concepto y si tienes dudas pregunta en comentarios... Por cierto, la clase `Usuario` no tiene por qué ser declarada abstracta. El problema que planteas se resuelve muy fácilmente con la herencia de clases.

#### Clase `Persona`

Esta sería tu clase `Usuario`, pero me gusta más que se llama `Persona`

```
class Persona 
{ 
    protected $nombre;
    protected $apellido1;
    protected $apellido2;

    function __construct(string $nombre,string $apellido1,string $apellido2)
    {
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->apellido1=$apellido1;
        $this->apellido2=$apellido2;
    }

    public function getNombre()
    {
         return $this->nombre;
    }
    public function setNombre($pNombre)
    {
         $this->nombre=$pNombre;
    }
    public function getApellido1()
    {
         return $this->apellido1;
    }
    public function setApellido1($pApellido1)
    {
        $this->apellido1=$pApellido1;
    }
    public function getApellido2()
    {
        return $this->apellido2;
    }
    public function setApellido2($pApellido2)
    {
        $this->apellido2=$pApellido2;
    }  
}
```

---

#### Clase `Secretario`

Algo parecido habría que hacer para `Profesor` y para `Alumno`.
Hay comentarios aclaratorios en el código...

```
class Secretario extends Persona
{
    private $randomCode;
    private $propioDeSecretario;
    public function __construct(string $nombre,string $apellido1,string $apellido2, string $propioDeSecretario)
    {
        /*
            Llamamos al constructor del padre (Persona)
            y le pasamos las propiedades inherentes a TODA Persona
        */
        parent::__construct($nombre,$apellido1,$apellido2);
        /*
            Aquí seteamos lo que sea propio TODO Secretario
        */
        $this->propioDeSecretario=$propioDeSecretario;
        /*
            El $this->getNombre() que se invoca aquí es el de la clase padre (Persona)
        */
        $this->randomCode='S'.date('y').substr($this->getNombre(),4);
    }
    /*
        Getters y Setters propios
        NÓTESE que esta clase no tiene getters ni setters
        para Nombre, Apellido, etc, porque usará los de la clase padre (Persona)
    */
    public function getCode(){
        return $this->randomCode;
    }

    public function getPropioDeSecretario(){
        return $this->propioDeSecretario;
    }    

    public function setPropioDeSecretario($propioDeSecretario){
        $this->propioDeSecretario=$propioDeSecretario;
    }            
}
```

---

#### Ejemplo de uso en un contexto cualquiera

```
/*
    Uso en un contexto cualquiera
*/
$unSecretario=new Secretario("Pedro","García","Hernández","Soy un Secretario");
echo "Código generado: ".$unSecretario->getCode().PHP_EOL;
/* 
    Este método es de la clase Persona 
    y podemos usarlo con una instancia de Secretario
    gracias a la herencia
*/
echo "Nombre: ".$unSecretario->getNombre().PHP_EOL; 
echo "Propio: ".$unSecretario->getPropioDeSecretario().PHP_EOL; 
echo "\nEl objeto por dentro:\n\n";
var_dump($unSecretario);
```

**Salida:**

```
Código generado: S19o
Nombre: Pedro
Propio: Soy un Secretario

El objeto por dentro:

object(Secretario)#1 (5) {
  ["randomCode":"Secretario":private]=>
  string(4) "S19o"
  ["propioDeSecretario":"Secretario":private]=>
  string(17) "Soy un Secretario"
  ["nombre":protected]=>
  string(5) "Pedro"
  ["apellido1":protected]=>
  string(7) "García"
  ["apellido2":protected]=>
  string(10) "Hernández"
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, realmente estoy entendiendo poo con mas facilidad con estos ejemplos que me muestras, mi clase usuario la tengo abstracta porque le meto unas funciones que van a ser comunes para las tres clases que heredan pero que en cada clase tendra su funcionalidad propia, y si no lo he entendido mal, la abstracción es algo así no??